# как показать саму переменную, вместо содержимого?

Tags: php

У меня тут такая проблема:

```
$new_data = array($country,$gender);
$coocies = array($_SESSION['user_country'],$_SESSION['user_gender']);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($new_data); $i++){
if($new_data[$i] != $coocies[$i]){
"$coocies[$i]"(вот тут проблема) = $new_data[$i];
}
```

"$coocies[$i]"(вот тут проблема), дело в том, что я хочу, чтобы вместо содержимого этой куки он показывал саму "$_SESSION['user_country']", как мне это сделать ?

Comment: я не вижу в коде, чтобы что-то куда то показывало, переменной ```$coocies[$i]``` присваивается новое значение, уточни вопрос пожалуйста

Comment: В массиве $coocies[$i] 2 переменные СЕССИИ $_SESSION. 
В этих сессиях находятся данные(содержимое), и при цикле, он показывает содержимое, а мне надо, что бы сам $_SESSION принял новое значение $new_data[$i], а для этого должно выглядеть вот так $_SESSION['user_country'] = $country ($coocies[0] = $new_data[0])

Answer (score 0):

вот твой исходный код:

```
$country = 'user_country';
$gender  = 'user_gender_new';

$_SESSION['user_country'] = 'user_country';
$_SESSION['user_gender']  = 'user_gender';

$new_data = [$country, $gender];
$coocies = [$_SESSION['user_country'], $_SESSION['user_gender']];

print_r($coocies);//исходный массив


for ($i = 0; $i < count($new_data); $i++){
    if($new_data[$i] != $coocies[$i]){
        $coocies[$i] = $new_data[$i];//тут ты присвоил новое значение
    }
}

print_r($coocies);//изменённый массив

/*
Array
(
    [0] => user_country
    [1] => user_gender
)
Array
(
    [0] => user_country
    [1] => user_gender_new
)
*/
```

вот тот код, который ты просишь:

```
$newData = ['user_country', 'user_gender_new'];

$_SESSION['user_country'] = 'user_country';
$_SESSION['user_gender']  = 'user_gender';

print_r($_SESSION);//исходный массив

reset($_SESSION);//на всякий случай
foreach($newData as $v)
    {
        if($v != $_SESSION[current($_SESSION)])
            {
                $_SESSION[current($_SESSION)] = $v;
            }

        next($_SESSION);
    }
unset($v);

print_r($_SESSION);//изменённый массив

/*
Array
(
    [user_country] => user_country
    [user_gender] => user_gender
)
Array
(
    [user_country] => user_country
    [user_gender] => user_gender_new
)
*/
```

проблема в том, что ты зависишь от порядка в обоих массивах, если ты сможешь добавить к массиву $newData строковые ключи, т.е. привести массивы к единому виду по ключам, это позволит тебе избежать проблем и сделать так:

```
$newData  = ['user_country' => 'user_country', 'user_gender' => 'user_gender_new'];

$_SESSION = ['user_country' => 'user_country', 'user_gender' => 'user_gender'];

print_r($_SESSION);//исходный массив

//в $newData всегда меньше либо равно ключей, поэтому его обхожу
//в $newData и $_SESSION всегда совпадают ключи иначе в if() добавлю isset($_SESSION[$k])
foreach($newData as $k=>$v)
    {
        if($_SESSION[$k] != $v)//значения одинаковых ключей не совпали
            {
                $_SESSION[$k] = $v;//новое значение
            }
    }
unset($k,$v);

print_r($_SESSION);//изменённый массив

/*
Array
(
    [user_country] => user_country
    [user_gender] => user_gender
)
Array
(
    [user_country] => user_country
    [user_gender] => user_gender_new
)
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

Надо просто в массиве

```
$coocies = array($_SESSION['user_country'],$_SESSION['user_gender']);
```

добавить `''` к переменнам

Например:

```
$coocies = array('$_SESSION["user_country"]','$_SESSION["user_gender"]')
```

Comment: а сравнивать он как будет? ```if($new_data[$i] != $coocies[$i]){...```

Comment: @Василий лучше использовать сравнение `!==`

Comment: в данном случае это лишнее, хотя лучше всегда сравнивать с учётом типа